# How to sync assets with nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using the plugin [Nativescript Splashscreen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-splashscreen) to add a Splashscreen to my App. First time i added, it worked perfectly. So i decided to make some improvements. I added some Images to the App_resources and i changed some things in the plugin code located at the **node_modules** Folder. Then i have done those steps:

I removed the android **tns platform remove android**

I added the android **tns platform add android**

then i ran the build **tns build android**

but when i run : **tns run android --emulator --geny myapp** the images and the changes that i maded doesnt appear.

How can i refresh and build my application so that new images and plugin changes, which was maded, can be see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android apps typically will require to be uninstalled from the emulator when a new .apk is being introduced to the device. Many things get cached on the device and the CLI running a new .apk won't override the existing app. Try uninstalling the current app from the emulator (normal way to uninstall android apps works on emulators) then execute `tns run android` you don't need the other flags with the `tns run android` command either. It will be livesyncing once it is installed on the emulator and the CLI should find your running emulator, unless you have some setup issues that prevent it from finding it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: In addition, I'd like to say that version 3.0 will perform rebuilds whenever necessary, so manually reinstalling the application should not be necessary.

Comment: it doesnt work! I removed, added android, uninstall from the emulator, rebuild and run. No Changes.

Comment: How wrong? @BradMartin it's work. But don't refresh when i changed an asset with another one.

Comment: You haven't posted any code so I have no idea what you're actually doing. Why I said, `Maybe your code is wrong...` because I don't know what you're doing.